# NSCursor: "set" method has no effect

Tags: xcode, macos, cocos2d-iphone, nscursor

I am working on a Mac application with Xcode (using cocos2d), trying to configure the cursor, and the "set" method does not seem to have any effect in some cases...

I already had a hard time to set my cursor at the launch of the application (NSTimer to set it after the application was really launched), and now I just want it to display another image when the user clicks; I use NSNotification for that, my cursor class receives the notification, then it is supposed to set the new image, then... nothing.

Here is some code which may help:

```
-(void) click  
{  
    CCLOG(@"Click");  
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"point_pressed" ofType:@"png"];  
    NSImage *cursorImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingFile:path] autorelease];  
    NSCursor *cursor = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:cursorImage hotSpot:[[NSCursor currentCursor] hotSpot]];  
    [cursor set];  
}
```

In the initialization:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(updateCursor:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

And the method:

```
-(void) updateCursor:(id)sender  
{  
    CCLOG(@"Update cursor");  
    [[self.cursorsDict objectForKey:@"point"] set];  
}
```

The "updateCursor" method is also called when the application becomes active, and then it works fine, the correct cursor is displayed.
I have tried many things, pop and push methods, "setOnMouseEnter" (although I don't use rect yet), but no result...
Has anyone a clue about this?

Edit:

Stranger, I wrote the appWake method:

```
-(void) appWake
{
    int i = rand()%3;
    if(i==0)
        [[self.cursorsDict objectForKey:@"point"] set];
    else if(i==1)
        [[self.cursorsDict objectForKey:@"point_pressed"] set];
    else if(i==2)
        [[self.cursorsDict objectForKey:@"open"] set];
    self.state = ECursorState_Point;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(appWake) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Which is called by a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWake) name:EVENT_APPLICATION_DID_BECOME_ACTIVE object:nil];
```

Set in the appDelegate by:

```
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:EVENT_APPLICATION_DID_BECOME_ACTIVE object:nil];
}
```

And when it's called by this notification, it works fine, the cursor changes randomly; but if I remove the notification in applicationDidBecomeActive and call it somewhere else in my code, then it does not do anything (although I checked that it is called)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it has been awhile. But I had a similar problem.

For some reason [cursor set] doesn't work when being called from the application events.

Here is how I did it:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(doChangeCursor) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

- (void) doChangeCursor
{
    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"statusBarImage" ofType:@"tiff"];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];
    NSCursor *cursor = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:image hotSpot:NSMakePoint(0, 0)];
    [cursor set];    
}
```

I hope this is able to help someone.

Comment: Well, it would not surprise me at all that this is the answer! I don't really have the motivation to try it, because it is some old code (and I found another way to do this by using a sprite instead of the cursor), but it seems pretty reasonable since most of the graphical functions do not work when called from an event. So I'll mark it as the answer, and I'll edit this if I have the chance to try it.

Comment: This `doChangeCursor` seems to be leaking instances of `NSImage` and `NSCursor`.

Comment: JWWalker, you are aware that we have had ARC for a while?

Comment: This works reliably compared to just setting it.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Working solution for me to change the cursor from system event was to wrap the cursor set inside async like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.customCursor.set()
}
```

(Swift 3)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could not find any solution to this problem. I had to use a workaround: handle a sprite cursor set at the position of the cursor...