# Is it possible to detect in an app the opening/ending of the dashboard?

Tags: macos, cursor, dashboard

In the app I'm working on, a custom cursor is displayed using an image, and the system cursor is hidden (at least when it's over the app). The main system notifications are used to hide/display the system cursor, and it works fine, except with the dashboard: when the dashboard is launched (using fn+F12), the system cursor appears (the app is still running behind the dashboard), and when the dashboard is exited, well... the system cursor is still here (since we did not send a specific message to hide it again).

Would somebody know how to detect those changes? I thought about getting the keys to know when the dashboard is launched, but the problem is that there are several ways to close it, and what is more the app can be launched as the dashboard is opened...

Comment: You might want to look into [NSCursor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [cursor rects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CursorMgmt/Tasks/ChangingCursors.html), if you haven't. Then the system can automatically show and hide your cursor for your.

Comment: I began in this direction, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430236/nscursor-set-method-has-no-effect
And finally the sprite method was maybe better in my case because I often change the scale of the cursor, and I don't remember a NSCursor method allowing to do that.